# The sort-button does not work in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a JSON file, that I need to parse it into collection and render it to HTML pageand then I need to add a button, that will sort this collection and redraw it on page.
That the code, that I made:

That's the part about model, collection and sorting:

```
           var Profile = Backbone.Model.extend();

            var ProfileList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Profile,
                url: 'profiles.json',
                selectedStrategy: "count",


                comparator: function (property){
                    return selectedStrategy.apply(model.get(property));
                },

                strategies: {
                    count: function (model) {return model.get("count");},
                    name: function (model) {return model.get("name");}

                },

                changeSort: function (sortProperty) {
                    this.comparator = this.strategies[sortProperty];
                },


                initialize: function () {
                    this.changeSort("count");

                }, 


            });
```

It's the View and the Button:

```
            var ProfileView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: "body",
                template: _.template($('#profileTemplate').html()),
                Sort: null,


                initialize: function() {
                    this.Sort = new ReSortView();
                    this.bind('all', this.render());
                },

                render: function() {
                    _.each(this.model.models, function(profile){
                        var profileTemplate = this.template(profile.toJSON());
                        $(this.el).append(profileTemplate);
                    }, this);

                    return this;
                },

                ReSort: function (){
                    console.log("111");
                    this.model.changeSort("name");
                },

                events: {
                    "click .Sort": "ReSort",
                    //"click.NSort": "NSort"
                },

            });

            var ReSortView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: $("#Sort")
            });

            var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: "body",
                initialize: function() {

                    var profiles = new ProfileList();    
                    var profilesView = new ProfileView({
                        model: profiles
                    });


                    profiles.bind('all', function () {
                        profilesView.render();
                    });

                    profiles.fetch({success: function (model,resp) { console.log(resp);}});


                }
            });

            var App = new AppView();

        });
```

The question is why when I run it, everything seems to be ok, but the sorting does't work, and FireBug saying nothing and Button just writing into the consol.

P.S. I'm new in WEB developing and exactly in JS\Backbone.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just changing the [`comparator`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator):

```
changeSort: function (sortProperty) {
    this.comparator = this.strategies[sortProperty];
}
```

won't re-sort the collection, the collection has no way of know that the `comparator` has changed unless you tell it. You need to force the issue by calling [`sort`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-sort):

```
changeSort: function (sortProperty) {
    this.comparator = this.strategies[sortProperty];
    this.sort();
}
```

---

And a few other things while I'm here:

1. Your initial `comparator`:

   ```
   comparator: function (property){
       return selectedStrategy.apply(model.get(property));
   }
   ```

   is invalid (unless you have a global `selectedStrategy` defined somewhere), you should probably just leave it out and let `initialize` set it up by calling `changeSort`.
2. `this.bind('all', this.render());` does nothing useful, [`bind`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on) wants a function as the second argument but `this.render()` *calls* the `render` method. You probably don't want a `this.bind` call there at all and if you do, you'd want to say `this.bind('all', this.render)`.
3. Views handle the `collection` option similarly to how the handle the `model` option in [their constructor](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

   > There are several special options that, if passed, will be attached directly to the view: `model`, `collection`, `el`, `id`, `className`, `tagName` and `attributes`.

   so, if your view is collection-based, you'd want to say `new View({ collection: ... })` and use `this.collection` instead of `this.model` to avoid confusion.
4. Collections have various [Underscore functions built-in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) so don't say:

   ```
   _.each(this.model.models, ...
   ```

   when you can say this instead:

   ```
   this.collection.each(...
   ```
5. View's have a jQuery wrapped version of [`el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) built in so you can use [`this.$el`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-%24el) instead of `$(this.el)` (which rebuilds the jQuery wrapper each time you call it).

Comment: if I add this.sort(); to the comparator, all that it does - duplicating lines in the file. i try this and it doesn't do anything good

Comment: Did you add a `this.sort()` to the comparator or `changeSort`?

Comment: and this.$el insted of $(this.el) does not work too... FireBug saying - TypeError: this.$el is undefined

Comment: to the changeSort. excuse my mistake. you can see how it works here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/littlemyx/WBPqk/60/)

Comment: What version of Backbone are you using? Something ancient like 0.3.3 perhaps?

Comment: 0.5.2 if I use the last version FireBug throws me errors like this         TypeError: _.has is not a function                                 

if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) {

backbone.js (line 1539)

Comment: 0.5.2 is ancient, upgrade to the latest. Then compare your fiddle to this one (which has my changes as noted above and removes the old stuff from the view before re-rendering): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ThjRZ/

Comment: Thanks a lot! and may I ask another one question? How should change my collection, or view, or something else to work with JSONs like {a:b,[{c:d},..]}. It seems to me that the trouble is in templates but I do not understand how to work with them properly

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, perhaps you should ask another question so that you can provide more details.

Comment: The stuff inside `<%= ... %>` is just JavaScript so you can show things like that the same way you'd access them in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `changeSort` method on the `model` but that method is on your `collection` (as it should be)

Comment: But my collection is model for my view, isn't it?

Comment: Oh I see that now. Well you shouldn't change the naming convention. A `model` is never a `collection` and vice-versa. Could you set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: here it is: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/littlemyx/T8Ttt/) but it doesn't working there...

Comment: @Littlemyx: You need to include Backbone and Underscore in the *External References* panel in the sidebar. You can start here if you'd like: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HDHZD/

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/littlemyx/WBPqk/62/) and I find another one bug - it's adding new lines when activatin the sort-button